# How to increase maxConnections on tomcat

Tags: windows, tomcat, java, tomcat7

We are trying to increase the number of connections on tomcat7. We are using NIO connector. Our setting on server.xml is set to 15000. But whenever we start the server, jmx export reports the value as 10000 connections.

We also tried to set it to -1 on high traffic server. But limit is stuck at 10000.

Any help is appreciated.

```
        port="80"
        protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
        minSpareThreads="10"
        maxSpareThreads="500"
        maxThreads="1000"
        enableLookups="false"
        
        debug="0"
        compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="1024"
        
        acceptCount="0"
        keepAliveTimeout="4000"         
        connectionTimeout="90000"           
        maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
        maxconnections="15000"
        disableUploadTimeout="true"
        redirectPort="443"
        
    />
```

***RESOLVED***

Yes, Piotr P. Karwasz his rightful, `maxconnections`, whereas it should be `maxConnections` (attributes are case-sensitive).
And

> Note that once the limit has been reached, the operating system may
> still accept connections based on the acceptCount setting.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

So, I increased acceptCount="15001" and I could inreased maxConnections="15000"

Comment: You have a typo in your configuration: you have `maxconnections`, whereas it should be `maxConnections` (attributes are case-sensitive). You should also find a warning in your logs, since `maxconnections` is an unknown property.